# does pageContext.findAttribute() function finds request scope also?

Tags: jsp, pagecontext

I have the following snippet in my jsp file:

```
<%
String name = request.getParameter("name");     
out.println(pageContext.findAttribute("name"));

%>

<br><br>

Name in request scope: <%=name %><br>
```

The output I get for passed parameter name = Swatanya is the following:

```
null 

Name in request scope: swatanya
```

why does findAttribute return null when there is value in name parameter of request scope ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between request parameter and attribute. Don't confuse between both.

If you are talking about query string then its passed as request parameter not attribute.

---

What [JspContext#findAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) states:

> Searches for the *named attribute* in page, request, session (if valid), and application scope(s) in order and returns the value associated or `null`.

What [ServletRequest#getParameter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) states:

> Returns the value of a *request parameter* as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist. *Request parameters are extra information sent with the request*. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the *query string* or posted form data.

---

You can try in this way if needed:

```
request.setAttribute("name", request.getParameter("name"));
```

---

**Note:**

> I suggest you to use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) instead of `Scriplet` that is more easy to use and *less error prone*.

Answer (score 0):

In first case you are searching in specific scope in request scope.
Where in second case you are searching in page,request ,session and application scope in order.it means if in case of get parameter if name is not present in request scope it will return null
and in find attribute it will search all the scope

Comment: Unfortunately your answer doesn't address the question. In question's scenario `pageContext.findAttribute("name")` is returning `null`. Whereas `request.getParameter("name")` is returning `swatanya`.